# What is the opposite command to "git add"?

Tags: git, github

After merging two git branches, if conflicts exist you can use the command `git add *` to resolve which accepts the local version of the code as most recent. How can I do the opposite of this command?

To give some background, I have two branches (call them master and develop for sake of ease) and for some reason git decided to remove some files from my develop branch (`git status` says `deleted by us:` in front of these files). I've tried to merge master back into develop (because these files are the only differences), now have conflicts and can't use `git -add` to resolve because I do not want loose these files.

Comment: not sure if this would help https://gist.github.com/stevenyap/7511407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `checkout` and re-add the file:

```
git checkout develop # go to develop branch first
git checkout master -- fileYouWant # getting the file from master
git add fileYouWant
```

Comment: Glad to help! :)